# pycharm - how to set highlighting level globally

Tags: python, pycharm

I am really stuck in this feature of pycharm.

I want pycharm to have hightlighting level at `syntax` only. but I have to level this everytime I open a file.

this is what I have to change always:

[image]

is it possible to set this to `syntax` level **globally**? I dont want to change the color or something, I just want to set it to syntax level only once and globally.

it would be a life-changing thing, if i could do this

Comment: @ChrisArena yes, but the level isnot changing at all.

Comment: What you probably want to do is go to the configure inspections from that menu and make your default inspection for the project to only check syntax errors. Would this do ?

Comment: This method (configuring inspections) is also answered well in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32902806/120398

Comment: @doniyor Have you tried to set the default settings?

Comment: I found this [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902645/change-highlighting-setting-for-every-file-by-default-in-pycharm-ce) that might help.

Comment: Try looking here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-and-ide-settings.html - you can probably modify these files (maybe manually) to reflect the settings you want.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way to get this done is by turning off the inspections which you do not require. But the side effect of it is it ends up crippling the pycharm ide.

This point has been raised previously too and this was the reply which was pushed out by the Pycharm dev team.

> No, and we have no plans to provide this possibility. In our point,
>   turning down the default highlighting level effectively cripples PyCharm, 
>   and if the only way PyCharm works for you is in a crippled state, then you > shouldn't try to suffer through this and should use another tool instead.

You can refer to this link for more details. Attitude issues i believe :(

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206598255-Is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-highlighting-level-to-Syntax-instead-of-Inspection-