# Change highlighting setting for every file (by default) in PyCharm CE

Tags: python, pycharm, highlighting

I just started using PyCharm as my IDE for Python. At the moment whenever I open a new .py file, I have to go to     Code -> Configure Current File Analysis..., and then change the highlighting to syntax (preference) for every individual .py file.

Is there a way to change this for every file automatically, by default?

First post on stackoverflow by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer not to see PyCharm's code inspections, I would suggest creating a new inspections profile that does no inspections. To do that, go to the Code -> Configure Current File Analysis dialog like you have been, but this time click on the `Configure inspections` link. At the top, click the "Manage" dropdown and copy the current profile into a new profile which you'll name "No inspections". Then uncheck everything, save the new inspections profile, and you'll be done. All new .py files should now be created under your "No inspections" profile.

Note that as far as I can tell, the inspection settings get saved per-project, rather than as a global setting. But changing the inspection profile once per project shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Comment: it's only a workaround on something that should have been implemented _globally_ by Jetbrains' devs but, still +1.